# LVM (stuck with SELECT A BOOT DISK)

Tags: lvm

LVM is a powerful tool. Installing ubuntu 18.04 on a virtual machine I got to the following step and now stuck
What I have:
.vdi local disk of 10GB.
5Gb is mounted to /
1Gb boot is mounted to /boot
vg0 as a LVM volume group
Ubuntu installer prompts for "Select a boot disk"
I can not find an option to mark my VBOX_HARDDISK_VB29a... as a boot disk
Would someone please comment!

Comment: here how it looks like https://i.imgur.com/jQlpwSD.png . An option to mark local disk as a Boot Device is greyed out

Comment: It looks like you are trying to boot from a disk that is inside the vg. /boot needs to be outside lvm.

Comment: Thank you Bruni! So, does that mean I should have at least 2 disks?

Comment: At least two partitions. Not necessarily disks.

Comment: Thanks again Bruni! I've been able to achieve my goals using your instructions and this video about LVM https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MeltFN-bXrQ

Comment: This installer is shit. Debian installer allows install system with boot on lvm without any problem.